# Issue with mount.cifs in Ubuntu [while accessing Windows samba share using a localServerUser]

Tags: ubuntu, samba, mount, server-message-block, cifs

I am having a hard time figuring out an issue while trying to mount a windows share in Ubuntu 10.04.

## Issue:

The problem is I am not able to mount a windows share using a serverLocalUser present in the windows-server. But I am able to use smbclient to access that same share using that same serverLocalUser. I am also able to mount the same share using a **domain user** who also has permission for that folder.

> **sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=serverLocalUser,password=passcode**
>
> mount error(13):Permission denied Refer to the mount.cifs(8 ) manual page (e.g. man
> mount.cifs)

## Troubleshooting done:

The following works:

1. smbclient //192.168.5.61/Share -U **localServerUser**
2. sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=**domainUser**,password=passcode
3. Mounting using the localServerUser using nautilus (which uses smbclient internally)

The following does not works:

1. sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=serverLocalUser,password=passcode,domain= WORKGROUP
2. sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=192.168.5.61\serverLocalUser,password=pas scode

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Sree

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=<domain_name>/serverLocalUser,password=passcode`

Comment: that also did not work. I get the same error. Also the serverLocalUser as I said earlier is not a domain user. It is a user created in that server locally.

Comment: Replace <domain_name> with IP address, but use slash instead of backslash.

Comment: I had tried that too. sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=192.168.5.61/serverLocalUser,password=passcode  and     sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=192.168.5.61\serverLocalUser,password=passcode   does not work

Comment: The following worked for me now: sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=192.168.5.61/serverLocalUser     **NOTE:I did not give the password in the command line; so it prompted me to enter the password; and when I entered it worked.**   Thanks for your help quanta.  But I want to use this in a non-interactive script which will run automatically at a given time. Any idea to make that working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for RHEL6

sudo mkdir -p /mnt/dev_support

sudo mount -t cifs //10.98.xx.xx/project /mnt/dev_support -o username='10.98.xx.xx/administrator'

Answer (score 0):

New version of mount.cifs now uses a specific domain option so you should use something like

```
 sudo mount.cifs //192.168.5.61/Share /mnt/share/ -o domain=domain_name,username=serverLocalUser,password=passcode
```

[c.f. man mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs)

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of attempts, I was able to get it working with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=3.1.1,rw,noperm,username=<microsoft-account>,password='<microsoft-account-password>',iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,user //<windows-device>/<windows-share-folder>/ /<linux-folder-path>/
```